# Web game where a boy invents a device that lets him see tiny creatures made of electricity

Tags: story-identification, video-games, animation

I remember being a fan of these promotional animations for a web game which I can't find. The plot was that a boy invents a device for reading electricity but instead it allows him to see tiny creatures made out of pure electricity.

Comment: Do you remember if they showed any aspect of the gameplay? What site you might have seen this on? If it was an advertisement unrelated to the site or something the site was reporting on?

Comment: https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11995/how-to-ask-a-good-video-game-story-id-question and https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question?noredirect=1&lq=1 will be useful lists for you to go through to elicit more details.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots I think they showed off gameplay. It was on it's own site. The videos were on the site itself made by the site. I think they made the animations to announce updates.

Comment: Do you remember anything about the gameplay? Was it a puzzle game? A platformer? RTS? Was it a Flash game? Was the animation cartoony or realistic? Were the eletricity creatures humanoid? Animal-life? Blobs?

Comment: @FuzzyBoots I didn't play the game much but I think it was a turn based pokemon knock off.

Comment: What you describe sounds to me like Eledees (aka Elebits) on the Nintendo Wii. Might the web game you're thinking of have been an advertisement for Eledees/Elebits?

Comment: @AaronF Thank you for helping answer this question but the art style was different overall darker and higher contrast. The electronic creatures were insectoid and robotic looking.

Comment: "The electronic creatures were insectoid and robotic looking" - could it be the first Chibi-Robo game? It was for the Gamecube, The enemies are little spider-robots called Spydorz: https://chibi-robo.fandom.com/wiki/Spydorz

Comment: @AaronF No I think the game had the limited animation that's indictive of flash animation and the cutscenes were more professionally animated but neither of were as pixelated as chibi robo.